# Boolean expression simplification using 3 variables

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

(!A B !C) + (B !C !D) + (!ACD) + (!BCD) + (!ABD)

= (!A B !C) + (B !C !D) + (!ACD) + (!BCD) + (!ABD)(1)

= (!A B !C) + (B !C !D) + (!ACD) + (!BCD) + (!ABD)(C + !C)

= (!A B !C) + (B !C !D) + (!ACD) + (!BCD) + (!ABDC) + (!ABD !C)

= (!A B !C) + (B !C !D) + (!ACD) + (!BCD) + (!ABDC) + (!ABD !C)

= (!A B !C) + (B !C !D) + (!ACD) + (!BCD) + (!ABCD) + (!AB !CD)

= (!A B !C) + (!AB !CD) + (B !C !D) + (!ACD) + (!ACDB) + (!BCD)

= [(!A B !C)(1 + D)] + (B !C !D) + [(!ACD)(1 + B)] + (!BCD)

= (!A B !C) + (B !C !D) + (!ACD) + (!BCD)

At this point I don't know how to continue the problem.
I verified it using a calculator and seems there is still some simplification to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two handy equivalences:

**Adjacency**

$PQ + P!Q=P$

**Absorption**

$P + PQ=P$

With that:

$$(!A B !C) + (B !C !D) + (!ACD) + (!BCD) + (!ABD)\overset{Adjacency \ x \ 2}=$$

$$(!A B !C D) + (!A B !C !D) + (B !C !D) + (!ABCD) + (!A!BCD)+ (!BCD) + (!ABD)\overset{Absorption \ x \ 4}=$$

$$(B !C !D) + (!BCD) + (!ABD)$$

I am sure that went a little quick though, so here is an explanation:

In step 1, I applied Adjacency to:

$(!A B !C)$ ... becoming $(!A B !C D) + (!A B !C !D)$

and to $(!ACD)$ ... becoming $(!ABCD) + (!A!BCD)$

Then, in step 2:

$(!A B !C D)$ got absorbed by $(!ABD)$

$(!A B !C !D)$ got absorbed by $(B !C !D)$

$(!ABCD)$ got absorbed by $(!ABD)$

$(!A!BCD)$ got absorbed by $(!BCD)$

More equivalences to put in your toolbox!

Now, notice that you effectively did Adjacency as well in your first few steps, expanding $(!ABD)$ to $(!ABCD)+(!AB!CD)$ ... and yet that one isn't as useful as the ones I did. So, I know you are going to ask: how did I know which terms to expand using Adjacency? Well, I created a little [K-map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map). Look it up!

Comment: Oh I finally understood what Adjacency is. Jesus Christ great work.
Thank you for taking all that time for this as well as the K-map.
On a side note, do you know of any good Boolean algebra calculators. I've tried plugging the problem in but it seems it gives me a different answer compared to yours.

Comment: @JohnJohnyPapaJohn Oh? What answer did your calculator give? Oh, and yeah, this form of Adjacency is a lot more intuitive than its dual I used in the other question (the $(P + Q)(P + !Q)=P$ one). Indeed, the $PQ+P!Q$ form is what you use in K-Maps

Comment: @JohnJohnyPapaJohn https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(not+A+and+B+and+not+C)+or+(B+and+not+C+and+not+D)+or+(not+A+and+C+and+D)+or+(not+B+and+C+and+D)+or+(not+A+and+B+and+D)  It shows the same DNF I arrived at .. but shows that the CNF is even more efficient yet. Looking back at the K-Map, I see that now as well. I missed that :(